# Let $G$ be a set with an internal operation $*$, if $(G, *)$ is a group then $a*b^{-1} \in G$*.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

I have a doubt with the definition of a group. I was wondering if the following statement is true:

> Let $G$ be a set with an internal operation $*$, if $(G, *)$ is a group then $a*b^{-1} \in G$*.

The converse seems false to me because if I consider $\mathbb{Z}$ endowed with the internal operation (the difference between integers), then $a-b \in \mathbb{Z} \forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}.$ But the associativity is not valid therefore $(\mathbb{Z}, -)$ is not a group Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Your boldface sentence is not a definition of a group. It already assumes that $(G,*)$ is a group, right? So how do we understand your title? I suppose you mean the definition of a *subgroup*.

Comment: sorry I misspelled the question, I just wanted to know if the sentence in bold is true or not. By hypothesis G is only a set with an internal operation *

Comment: If $G$ is only what you said here above, you should edit the sentence in bold in the OP. As it is stated now, it is trivially true.

Comment: For "$b^{-1}$" to make sense, you must posit that your operation has an identity, and that every element has an inverse. Even so, the proposal fails because you don't require associativity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it simple, recall that if $(G,*)$ is a group then by definition of group every element will have an inverse in $G$. So assuming that $b\in G$ we can say $b^{-1}\in G$. Now if $a\in G$ then we have both $a$ and $b^{-1}$ are in $G$. So again by definition of group we can say that $a*b^{-1}\in G$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course the bold sentence is true. This is an implication of the definition of a group as a group is closed under the operation and every element has an inverse. Your doubt or seeming contradiction does not make that much sense since $(\mathbb{Z},-)$ does not form a group. And "$-$" is not the 'endowed internal operation' in $\mathbb{Z}$. The addition "$+$" however is. And the minus sign just indicates the additive inverse of the element that comes after the sign. In your special case the bold sentence would be. $$(G,*)=(\mathbb{Z},+) \Rightarrow a*b^{-1}=a+(-b)=a-b \in \mathbb{Z}$$